# How to set a promise as the parameter for the onFulfilled callback in javascript promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to create a promise that response a promise, but I find it will resolve the promise recursively. For example:

```
const p = await Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(1))
// OR
const p = await new Promise((resolve) => resolve(Promise.resolve(1))
```

I hope the variable `p` is a `Promise<1>` rather than the value `1`.

How should I do?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what you are using this for? An example would be great.

Comment: Are you trying to make it so that you can in the future call `p().then()`?

Comment: Your wish conflicts the await operator behavior: 'The await operator is used to wait for a Promise': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await. Solution is to remove the await :).

Comment: I can't tell what you're really trying to do here, but you can't make a promise be the resolved value of another promise.  If you try, it will just chain them and the resolved value will be the resolved value of the promise, not the promise itself.  If you want to actually communicate back a promise, then you have to wrap it in an object and make the object be the resolved value of the first promise.  Then, you can get the promise out of that object.